# Why version 5.* does not satisfy dependency on >= 4.*?

Tags: debian, apt

As shown below, package `powertop` depends on `libstdc++6 (>= 4.4.0)` and I have `libstdc++6` version `5.2.1-23`, which should satisfy that dependency. Note the option `-t testing` does not influence whether or not I get this error. My system is mixed in that there are a few packages from the testing distribution, but the stable packages have higher priority so are not installed by default. My `libstdc++6` is from the testing distribution.

```
domas@nc4010-bl ~> sudo apt-get install -t testing powertop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 powertop : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
domas@nc4010-bl ~> dpkg -l libstdc++6
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  libstdc++6:i38 5.2.1-23     i386         GNU Standard C++ Library v3
```

Why is this dependency not satisfied?

Comment: Could this be a multilib issue? Are you on a 64 or 32bit system?

Comment: Rerun with the debug flag, please. Paste the result of `apt-get install -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=true -t testing powertop` in the question, not a comment .

Comment: @FaheemMitha http://pastebin.com/AjzeJjFu

Comment: @terdon 32bit system.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which version of powertop you are using but it seems that is a known issue :
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=795297

Comment: The bug report seems to have been closed as fixed. I might open a bug report.

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea but do you check if you are installing the last version ?

Comment: I would post a bug report with Debian. I believe that's the protocol, the package maintainer may then choose to report a bug with the upstream developers.